# Why am I getting a 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm learning so far, but this db ajax communication always makes me bang my head against the wall.

This is the controller:

```
function become_teacher()
{   
    $this->load->model('class_model');
    $data = array('user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'group_id' => $this->input->post('user_group') 
    );
    $this->class_model->change_to_teacher($data);
}
```

Here is the Model:

```
function change_to_teacher($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('user_groups', $data);
    return;     
}
```

And here is the script:

```
<p>Om du vill kunna skapa lektionen bli lärare. </p>
<button class="btn teacher">Bli lärare</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_id = $('.meta').text().trim();
    var user_group = '4';
    $('.teacher').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/testing/index.php/cours/become_teacher",
            data: "{ user_id: user_id, user_group: user_group }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `var user_id` is getting its data from the header file, not included here.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Most likely caused by a syntax / fatal error in your php code

Comment: Check your logs to see where exactly the error is occurring. I don't see anything strange here.

Comment: The 500 error will be server side, so nothing to do with your javascript code. Can you post any detail on the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed a letter when defining the table. Now its working...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the detail, but

```
data: "{ user_id: user_id, user_group: user_group}",
```

Should be

```
data: { "user_id": user_id, "user_group": user_group},
```

Comment: @Petter, please "close out" your question by posting an answer and then "accepting" your own answer.